# Using Nightmare web-scraping with React (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping, electron, nightmare

I'm setting up a create-react-app to pull from an API, display the results on the page and then when you click on one of the results I'd like to scrape some data from a URL passed from the API. I have tested the web scraper on its own, and I have tested the app on its own. Separate they work great, but when I'm trying to utilize both it comes up with errors:

(edit): this is line 1-4 from `node_modules/nightmare/node_modules/electron/` before the error

```
   1 | var fs = require('fs')
   2 | var path = require('path')
   3 |
   4 | var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt')
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'existsSync' of undefined
(anonymous function)
node_modules/nightmare/node_modules/electron/index.js:7
   4 | 
   5 | var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt');
   6 | 
>  7 | if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
   8 |   module.exports = path.join(__dirname, fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8'));
   9 | } else {
  10 |   throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again');
```

I've searched online and tried to implement some of the solutions but nothing has worked. I've tried to change the `requires` to `window.require`, and I've also deleted my node_modules folder to try and see if that was causing issues. Inside my node_modules folder, I've checked the node_modules folder and found the nightmare and electron modules, but they also have node_modules inside them, not sure if that is normal. I could use any help or suggestions you all might have!

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false });
// have this set to false for performance but can set to true if you'd like to see what it's scraping

export const webScraper = (link) => {
  nightmare
    .goto(link)
    .wait('.desc_text')
    .evaluate(() => {
      let thing = document.querySelector('.class_of_thing_grabbed');
      return thing.innerHTML
    })
    .end()
    .then((result) => {
      return result
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Search failed:', error);
    });
}
```

When running the nightmare app by itself it returns the inner HTML of the link that I wanted, but when I try and use it inside my React app the whole app crashes and I get that error.

Comment: You need to require `fs`: `const fs = require("fs")`

Comment: Thanks, @pguardiaro, but it's already required on line 1 of the electron module inside of node_modules. Are you saying I'm supposed to require it somewhere else?

Comment: Apparently you do because it's not defined there. Electron has 2 runtimes, a back-end and a browser, you want fs and nightmarejs in the back-end and react in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you are running Nightmare inside of an Electron window and, as a result, inside of a [*renderer process*](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#differences-between-main-process-and-renderer-process). Renderer processes don't have access to Node.js APIs like `fs` by default. You can change this by setting `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` to `true` when creating your `BrowserWindow` like so:

```
new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }
})
```

Note that this is **not recommended**: In the case that someone manages to inject a malicious script into your `BrowserWindow`, they will have access to all Node.js APIs and can compromise a user's system.

A more secure solution is to use Electron's [inter-process communication (IPC)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages) feature. Here's how that would work:

- Your renderer process running React (with `nodeIntegration` turned **off**) sends a message to the main process telling it to scrape a certain URL.
- Your main process which has access to all Node.js APIs by default runs the scraper and sends back the result as a message to the renderer process.
- The renderer process receives this message and displays the result.

This allows you to use possibly dangerous Node.js APIs without exposing them to the renderer process.